# Как вписать переменную в запрос?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть большой CSV (~1000 строк данных, 13 столбцов). Загружаю его в DataFrame (`cur_stat`) и пытаюсь фильтровать:

```
curSubOrd = cur_stat.head(50)[['subordination']].values[0]
```

Фильтрую:

```
tmp = cur_stat.loc[cur_stat['id'] == curSubOrd, ['name']]
print("curSubOrd = <"+str(tmp.values[0])+">")
```

> ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (117,), (1,)).

Указывает на строку `loc`:

```
tmp = cur_stat.query("id == @curSubOrd")
print("curSubOrd = <"+str(tmp.values[0])+">")
```

> ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (117,), (1,)).

Указывает на строку `query`:

```
tmp = cur_stat[cur_stat['id'] == 556078]['name']
print("curSubOrd = <"+str(tmp.values[0])+">")
```

Работает.

```
tmp = cur_stat.query("id == 556078")['name']
print("curSubOrd = <"+str(tmp.values[0])+">")
```

Работает.

---

PS pandas  1.1.2 python  3.8.5

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение в переменной `curSubOrd` - должно быть скаляром, а у вас вектор, состоящий из одного элемента размерности `(1, )`. Сравнивать значения столбца можно либо с вектором той же размерности либо со скаляром.

Воспроизведение:

```
In [196]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":[4,5,6]}, index=list("abc"))

In [197]: df
Out[197]:
   a  b
a  1  4
b  2  5
c  3  6

In [198]: var = df.head(2)[["a"]].values[0]

In [199]: var
Out[199]: array([1])

In [200]: var.shape
Out[200]: (1,)
```

Попробуйте так:

```
In [202]: var = df.loc[df.index[1], "b"]

In [203]: var
Out[203]: 5

In [204]: df.query("b == @var")
Out[204]:
   a  b
b  2  5
```

или в вашем случае:

```
curSubOrd = cur_stat.loc[cur_stat.index[0], "subordination"]
```